# KDE plasmashell crashes after trying to search something

Tags: kde-plasma

i ran into quite an issue here.

I have been using KDE plasma for 6 months without a problem and i'm loving it.
However today (i'm not sure if this is related) after trying to install IPFS-desktop and some npm packages, plasmashell crashes after i try to search anything in the app menu (or whatever it's called).

After running plasmashell from command line i get this:

```
kf.activitiesstats: KActivities: Database can not be opened in WAL mode. Check the SQLite version (required >3.7.0). And whether your filesystem supports shared memory
kf.activitiesstats: KActivities ERROR: There is no database. This probably means that you do not have the Activity Manager running, or that something else is broken on your system. Recent documents and alike will not work!
KActivities: FATAL ERROR: Failed to contact the activity manager daemon
KActivities: FATAL ERROR: Failed to contact the activity manager daemon
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml" and "file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml"
qt.svg: <input>:406:376: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:407:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:408:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:408:393: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:409:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:410:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:411:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:412:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:379: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:631: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/homeworld-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-theme/wallpaper-withlogo" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-inksplat-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/lines-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/lines-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/moonlight-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/moonlight-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/wallpapers/Next" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/softwaves-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/softwaves-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/spacefun-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
KActivities: FATAL ERROR: Failed to contact the activity manager daemon
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml:524:9: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml:483:13: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/main.qml:30:1: QML DropArea (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "minimumWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml:483:13: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml:524:9: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml:544:5: QML Label: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
Plasma Shell startup completed
Plasma Shell startup completed
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml" and "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationHeader.qml"
org.kde.plasma.notifications: Failed to register Notification service on DBus
libkcups: CUPS-Get-Printers last error: 1030 No destinations added.
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.battery/contents/ui/CompactRepresentation.qml:53:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/extras/PlasmoidHeading.qml:56:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
libkcups: 0
libkcups: 0
KAStatsFavoritesModel::setFavorites is ignored
kf.activitiesstats: KActivities: Database can not be opened in WAL mode. Check the SQLite version (required >3.7.0). And whether your filesystem supports shared memory
kf.activitiesstats: KActivities ERROR: There is no database. This probably means that you do not have the Activity Manager running, or that something else is broken on your system. Recent documents and alike will not work!
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/FullRepresentation.qml:356: ReferenceError: headerSeparator is not defined
trying to show an empty dialog
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: No object for name "alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.3.analog-stereo.monitor"
```

And after searching something i get
`plasmashell: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name16`

The "There is no database" thing pops out to me and it makes sense that it crashes when searching but i haven't been able to find a solution. I'm guessing that's also the reason the kactivitymanager isn't starting.

I tried removing the ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd folder as per
https://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=149458.0
But it changed nothing. Everything else seems to be working fine, it's only when i search that it crashes.

I'm using KDE Plasma 5 with Debian Bullseye

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

After a long day, reinstalling KDE from scratch and other issues i figured it out.

I removed all sql files from /usr/local/lib

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libsql*
```

and now everything is back to normal.