# Black screen after KDE Plasma login

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I'm running KDE plasma in Kubuntu 21.10, when i login, the desktop does not appear but I can run any application through the terminal normally (Firefox,kate,Dolphin,gns3..), everything work except plasma desktop. where is the problem?

i did tried deleting cache and removing the file in:

```
~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

but nothing had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the command `plasmashell`, it showed a plasma desktop for a second then it gone, from the error that appeared, it seems that an error is related to  `libsql` so i deleted all the `libsql` files in directory `sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libsql*`, now everything work as charm.

here are some useful links that i used:

[KDE plasmashell crashes after trying to search something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296899/kde-plasmashell-crashes-after-trying-to-search-something)

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/uivsmo/black_screen_after_kde_plasma_login/

Answer (score 1):

same problem here.

to use "sudo tasksel" and reinstall KDE Plasma, worked for me on "Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"

regards.